# Can't access Google Cloud Datastore from Google Kubernetes Engine cluster

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a simple application that Gets and Puts information from a Datastore.

It works everywhere, but when I run it from inside the Kubernetes Engine cluster, I get this output:

```
Error from Get()
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Error from Put()
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

I'm using the `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` package and the Go language.

I don't know why I'm getting this error since the application works everywhere else just fine.

**Update:**

Looking for an answer I found this comment on Google Groups:

> In order to use Cloud Datastore from GCE, the instance needs to be
>   configured with a couple of extra scopes. These can't be added to
>   existing GCE instances, but you can create a new one with the
>   following Cloud SDK command:
>
> gcloud compute instances create hello-datastore --project
>    --zone  --scopes datastore userinfo-email

Would that mean I can't use Datastore from GKE by default?

**Update 2:**

I can see that when creating my cluster I didn't enable any permissions (which are disabled for most services by default). I suppose that's what's causing the issue:

[image]

Strangely, I can use CloudSQL just fine even though it's disabled (using the `cloudsql_proxy` container).

Comment: Did you just try to edit permission on instances itself?

Comment: @vjdhama How do I edit it? there is not a edit button at permissions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So what I learnt in the process of debugging this issue was that:

- During the creation of a Kubernetes Cluster you can specify permissions for the GCE nodes that will be created.
- If you for example enable Datastore access on the cluster nodes during creation, you will be able to access Datastore directly from the Pods without having to set up anything else.
- If your cluster node permissions are disabled for most things (default settings) like mine were, you will need to create an appropriate Service Account for each application that wants to use a GCP resource like Datastore.
- Another alternative is to create a new node pool with the `gcloud` command, set the desired permission scopes and then migrate all deployments to the new node pool (rather tedious).

So at the end of the day I fixed the issue by creating a Service Account for my application, downloading the JSON authentication key, creating a Kubernetes secret which contains that key, and in the case of Datastore, I set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of the mounted secret JSON key.

This way when my application starts, it checks if the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable is present, and authenticates Datastore API access based on the JSON key that the variable points to.

Deployment YAML snippet:

```
  ...
  containers:
  - image: foo
    name: foo
    env:
    - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
      value: /auth/credentials.json
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo-service-account
      mountPath: "/auth"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo-service-account
    secret:
      secretName: foo-service-account
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling some hours, I was also able to connect to the datastore. Here are my results, most of if from [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform):

1. Create Service Account

   `gcloud iam service-accounts create [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]`
2. Get full iam account name

   `gcloud iam service-accounts list`

   The result will look something like this:

   `[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@[PROJECT_NAME].iam.gserviceaccount.com`
3. Give owner access to the project for the service account

   `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_NAME] --member serviceAccount:[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@[PROJECT_NAME].iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/owner`
4. Create key-file

   `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create mycredentials.json --iam-account [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@[PROJECT_NAME].iam.gserviceaccount.com`
5. Create `app-key` Secret

   `kubectl create secret generic app-key --from-file=credentials.json=mycredentials.json`

   This `app-key` secret will then be mounted in the deployment.yaml
6. Edit deyployment file

deployment.yaml:

```
...
spec:
 containers:
 - name: app
   image: eu.gcr.io/google_project_id/springapplication:v1
   volumeMounts:
   - name: google-cloud-key
     mountPath: /var/secrets/google
   env:
   - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
     value: /var/secrets/google/credentials.json
   ports:
   - name: http-server
     containerPort: 8080
 volumes:
 - name: google-cloud-key
   secret:
     secretName: app-key
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a minimalistic Dockerfile like:

```
FROM SCRATCH
ADD main /
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/main"]
```

which kept my go app in an indefinite "hanging" state when trying to connect to the GCP Datastore. After LOTS of playing I figured out that the SCRATCH Docker image might be missing certain environment tools / variables / libraries which the Google cloud library requires. Using this Dockerfile now works:

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
ADD main /
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/main"]
```

It does not require me to provide the google credentials environment variable. The library seems to automatically understand where it's running in (maybe from the context.Background() ?) and automatically uses a default service account which Google creates for you when you create your cluster on GKE.